# phpMyAdmin 5.2 how to have multiple tabs with same session?

Tags: phpmyadmin

With phpMyAdmin 5.0, I could sign in to a database and then duplicate my browser tab a few times in order to see related records in an easier manner than switching between tables within a single tab. After upgrading the server's php to 8 (from 7), I had to update phpMyAdmin. Now, each new browser tab wants its own login, and immediately invalidates the previous tab.

Can I get the old behavior back? The phpMyAdmin is installed on the same server as the MariaDB I am accessing, and the DB access is limited to the localhost, no outside connections.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this problem only exists when I use the 'duplicate tab' option in my browser. Opening a new tab and then navigating to the phpMyAdmin URL works correctly, so that will do.